# How to change a specific value of an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a XML file with structure similar to :

```
<config>
    <property>
        <name>prop1</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop2</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop3</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop4</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
</config>
```

How can i change the value of prop3 to 10 using python xml.etree.ElementTree?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

See below.
(There is no need to loop over all elements - use the 'find' method and point directly to the element you want to modify. There is no need to use an external library as well.).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<config>
    <property>
        <name>prop1</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop2</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop3</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>prop4</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
</config>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
prop3 = root.find(".//property/[name='prop3']")
prop3_val = prop3.find('value')
print(prop3_val.text)
prop3_val.text = 10
print(prop3_val.text)
```

output

```
3
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (just have a look at the lxml documentation).

```
import lxml.etree as ET

file = "file.xml"

# Grab the root (config node)
root = ET.parse(file).getroot()

# Grab all 'property' nodes
properties = root.findall("property")

# Iterate over them
for property in properties:
  # Find the property with name 'prop3'
  if property.find("name").text == "prop3":
    # Update the value to ten
    property.find("value").text = "10"

# Write back the modified file
with open(file, "w") as f:
  f.write(ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

Bonus, you can change the last line to `f.write(ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))` to get a nice XML file with indentation and returns.